# Why do my keyboard events get halted by mouse movement?

Tags: python, events, keyboard, pygame, mouse

I have a program in pygame that takes mouse input and keyboard input like follows:

```
for event in events:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            for k in other:
                k.move(archerspeed, 0)
                k.draw(k.x, k.y)
            for k in arrows:
                Arrow().draw(k[0], k[1])
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            for k in other:
                k.move(-archerspeed, 0)
                k.draw(k.x, k.y)
            for k in arrows:
                Arrow().draw(k[0], k[1])
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            for k in other:
                k.move(0, archerspeed)
                k.draw(k.x, k.y)
            for k in arrows:
                Arrow().draw(k[0], k[1])
    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            for k in other:
                k.move(0, -archerspeed)
                k.draw(k.x, k.y)
            for k in arrows:
                Arrow().draw(k[0], k[1])

if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and time.time() - arrowtime > 1:
    myarcher.shoot(myarcher.x, myarcher.y)
    arrowtime = time.time()
```

Everything works fine in this game, and my object responds to the keyboard events, **until the mouse starts moving. While the mouse is moving, no matter how hard I bang my keyboard, nothing happens.**

Why is this? Is there any way to prevent this from occurring?

Comment: First of all, your indentation seems broken. Could you provide your entire main loop or better, a running, selfcontained example that reproduces your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that your mouse events are completely halting your events. I suggest filtering them out using list comprehension beforehand:

```
try:
    events = [event for event in events if event.key >= 273 and event.key <= 276]
except AttributeError:
    continue
```

This makes sure that the keys are one of the arrow keys. Otherwise, remove it from the list of events.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot. However, I modified the keys that it removed so that it would work for the space bar :). Thanks!